# Jerarquía de clases Prestashop 1.6 - Uso clases no declaradas

Tags: php, prestashop

En prestashop 1.6.x hay algunas clases propias (no de módulos) que extienden la clase "Module", p.e. tenemos en **"presatshop/classes/modules/ModuleGraph.php"** la siguiente declaración:

```
abstract class ModuleGraphCore extends Module
{
...
```

En el mismo directorio tenemos **"Module.php"** con la declaración:

```
abstract class ModuleCore
{
...
```

No encuentro clases que extiendan **ModuleCore**, ni la definición de la clase **Module**. ¿Donde está esta declaración?

Igualmente la clase abstracta "AdminControllerCore", declarada en "AdminController", hereda de "Controller", que esta declarada como "ControllerCore" dentro del fichero "Controller.php".

Todo ésto me parece un poco extraño, por lo que pensé que debía haber alguna especie de mapeo de clases que modificara las declaraciones a la hora de cargarlas, encontré un listado de clases en "prestashop/cache/class_index.php" que se esta cargando en "prestashop/classes/PrestaShopAutoload.php".

¿Alguien sabe el porque de este sistema? ¿Si tiene que ver con la falta de namespaces en el lenguaje cuando se escribió esta versión, motivos de seguridad, un patrón de diseño o alguna otra razón?

Answer (score 0):

Según su github esta en 
**PrestaShop/classes/module/Module.php**

Fuente:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/tree/1.6.1.x/classes/module